Good practice when estimating nuisance parameters for doubly robust effect estimation
I'm involved in a project that uses data from various medical registers to perform observational studies with the goal of treatment effect estimation. It is already decided that studies will by default use a particular implementation of TMLE, but some recent literature (e.g., 1, 2) made me unsure about good practice when modeling treatment and outcome mechanisms, particularly regarding sample splitting procedures.
My current understanding is (roughly) the following. If we want to be safe, we should perform nested cross-validation. The inner layer of cross-validation is to ensure nuisance models are not overfit. This is how we select the model that approximates the "truth" as well as possible. The outer layer of cross-validation is to estimate standard errors. If we use very flexible (e.g., tree-based) estimators for nuisance models, we cannot expect valid inference, unless we perform the targeting step and estimate standard errors in held-out data. Technically, we could omit the inner layer of cross-validation (for model comparison) if we only have one estimator of nuisance parameters. Suppose we had an exact configuration of gradient boosted trees we liked; we could apply it to a number of training folds and use the corresponding test folds for variance estimation. We could also omit the outer layer of cross-validation (for variance estimation) if we restricted estimators to those within the Donsker class (e.g., GLMs or MARS). So no cross-validation is necessary if we use some pre-specified GLM. If we wanted to compare different GLM specifications, we could compare them via CV (to select the one closest to the truth), but still do not need to use held-out data for variance estimation.
Does that sound reasonable? On thing I noticed is that the cross-fitting procedure recommended by Zivich & Breskin (2) also estimates treatment models and outcome models in separate data (adding essentially another necessary data split), which is a procedure I haven't seen before. Is it recommended to do this as well?
References:
(1) Benkeser, D., Carone, M., Laan, M. V. D., & Gilbert, P. B. (2017). Doubly robust nonparametric inference on the average treatment effect. Biometrika, 104(4), 863-880.
(2) Zivich, P. N., & Breskin, A. (2021). Machine learning for causal inference: on the use of cross-fit estimators. Epidemiology, 32(3), 393-401.

Yes, your understanding is correct. The Donsker class condition ensures that the empirical process of the efficient influence function (EIF) converges weakly to a Gaussian process, which allows for standard asymptotic inference. This condition can be relaxed to accommodate data-adaptive estimators, but doing so typically requires techniques like sample-splitting and evaluation on held-out data, which can reduce the effective sample size.
For doubly-robust estimators like AIPW, one-step corrections, or TMLE to be RAL (regular asymptotically linear), additional conditions must be satisfied (beyond identifiability, pathwise differentiability and positivity). A crucial requirement is the behavior of the second-order remainder, which demands that certain products of the nuisance parameter estimators converge at specific rates. For instance, when estimating the average treatment effect (ATE), it is sufficient for both the propensity score model and the outcome model to converge at a parametric rate of $\mathcal{O}(n^{-1/4})$.
It's also important to note that the estimator of the asymptotic variance of these estimators is not typically doubly-robust, meaning it requires the consistent estimation of all nuisance parameters involved to be consistent.
